# How to collapse ExpandPanel in window 10 uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using ExpandPanel to expand and collapse list as follows.

```
 <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="test1" HeaderContent="Test1" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False">
                                                <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="yearlyAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                                </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                            </local:ExpandPanel>

    <local:ExpandPanel HeaderContent="Test2" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False">
                                                <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="guruAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                                </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                            </local:ExpandPanel>
```

Now, i want to expand one ExpandPanel at a time.
But in this case, if i expand one panel and clicking on the next panel, the first panel is not collapsing. So, both the panels are in expanded state only. That looks irritating.
I have tried in the C# end as follows.

```
test1.IsExpanded=false;
```

But it is not working.
I am using Expandanel.cs class as below.

```
public ExpandPanel()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpandPanel);
        }

        private bool _useTransitions = true;
        private VisualState _collapsedState;
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton toggleExpander;
        private FrameworkElement contentElement;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(object),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), null);

        public object HeaderContent
        {
            get { return GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
        }

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        private void changeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
        {
            if (IsExpanded)
            {
                if (contentElement != null)
                {
                    contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expanded", useTransitions);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Collapsed", useTransitions);
                _collapsedState = (VisualState)GetTemplateChild("Collapsed");
                if (_collapsedState == null)
                {
                    if (contentElement != null)
                    {
                        contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            toggleExpander = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton)
                GetTemplateChild("ExpandCollapseButton");
            if (toggleExpander != null)
            {
                toggleExpander.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
                    toggleExpander.IsChecked = IsExpanded;
                    changeVisualState(_useTransitions);
                };
            }
            contentElement = (FrameworkElement)GetTemplateChild("Content");
            if (contentElement != null)
            {
                _collapsedState = (VisualState)GetTemplateChild("Collapsed");
                if ((_collapsedState != null) && (_collapsedState.Storyboard != null))
                {
                    _collapsedState.Storyboard.Completed += (object sender, object e) =>
                    {
                        contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    };
                }
            }
            changeVisualState(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given class, the `IsExpanded` property doesn't affect anything when it's changing. You can add a callback in the dependency property's definition to change the visual state when the property changed:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(ExpandPanel), 
        new PropertyMetadata(true, IsExpanded_Changed));

private static void IsExpanded_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var panel = (ExpandPanel)sender;
    panel.toggleExpander.IsChecked = IsExpanded;
    panel.changeVisualState(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tibor, thanks for reply. As you said i have added the property but it is behaving in the same way.  How the first panel will be collapsed, when i expanded the second one. As said in the code, if i expand the second panel, in the sender i will get only the second panel data  and more over i won't get the first panel data. How to collapse the first one. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's only a fix for your `test1.IsExpanded=false;` issue. So you can expand/collapse it programmatically when you want.